# How can i make a static header for react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

when I use header in screen options, it creates same header for every screen, but I want exactly one header.

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {Home, Account, Cart} from '../screens';
import Header from '../components/Header';

const Router = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<NavigationParams>();
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        header(props) {
          return <Header props={props} />;
        },
        animation: 'slide_from_right',
      }}
      initialRouteName="Home">
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Account" component={Account} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Cart" component={Cart} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default Router;
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'exactly one header'? Doesn't this already show the same header for all stack screens?

Answer (score 0):

You need the stack header to be shown instead of showing the screen header.
So inside of `screenOptions` you need to set `headerShown: false`

**Note**: This is for react-navigation 5.x and above. If you are using an older version you need to use:

```js
    navigationOptions: {
        headerVisible: false,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In React navigation x6 there is a new property for screen options

```
    headerMode: 'float',
```

now be sure to add this screenOptions to your Stack.Navigator